# Transform failed during publishing of map_odom transform

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, hector-slam, tf

i am trying publish tf and odom. my problem is that i always get this error:

```
[ERROR] [1698638471.209513778]: Transform failed during publishing of map_odom transform: Lookup would require extrapolation 0.567969187s into the future.  Requested time 1698638469.812094927 but the latest data is at time 1698638469.244125605, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [odom]
```

And when i look at my tf tree, odom is not publish to base_link as i expected [image]

Here's the odom publisher node:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/Int16.h"
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <cmath>
 
// Create odometry data publishers
ros::Publisher odom_data_pub;
ros::Publisher odom_data_pub_quat;
nav_msgs::Odometry odomNew;
nav_msgs::Odometry odomOld;
 
// Initial pose
const double initialX = 0.0;
const double initialY = 0.0;
const double initialTheta = 0.00000000001;
const double PI = 3.141592;
 
// Robot physical constants
const double TICKS_PER_REVOLUTION = 535; // For reference purposes.
const double WHEEL_RADIUS = 0.033; // Wheel radius in meters
const double WHEEL_BASE = 0.17; // Center of left tire to center of right tire
const double TICKS_PER_METER = 3100; // Original was 2800
 
// Distance both wheels have traveled
double distanceLeft = 0;
double distanceRight = 0;
 
// Flag to see if initial pose has been received
bool initialPoseRecieved = false;
 
using namespace std;
 
// Get initial_2d message from either Rviz clicks or a manual pose publisher
void set_initial_2d(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped &rvizClick) {
 
  odomOld.pose.pose.position.x = rvizClick.pose.position.x;
  odomOld.pose.pose.position.y = rvizClick.pose.position.y;
  odomOld.pose.pose.orientation.z = rvizClick.pose.orientation.z;
  initialPoseRecieved = true;
}
 
// Calculate the distance the left wheel has traveled since the last cycle
void Calc_Left(const std_msgs::Int16& leftCount) {
 
  static int lastCountL = 0;
  if(leftCount.data != 0 && lastCountL != 0) {
         
    int leftTicks = (leftCount.data - lastCountL);
 
    if (leftTicks > 10000) {
      leftTicks = 0 - (65535 - leftTicks);
    }
    else if (leftTicks < -10000) {
      leftTicks = 65535-leftTicks;
    }
    else{}
    distanceLeft = leftTicks/TICKS_PER_METER;
  }
  lastCountL = leftCount.data;
}
 
// Calculate the distance the right wheel has traveled since the last cycle
void Calc_Right(const std_msgs::Int16& rightCount) {
   
  static int lastCountR = 0;
  if(rightCount.data != 0 && lastCountR != 0) {
 
    int rightTicks = rightCount.data - lastCountR;
     
    if (rightTicks > 10000) {
      distanceRight = (0 - (65535 - distanceRight))/TICKS_PER_METER;
    }
    else if (rightTicks < -10000) {
      rightTicks = 65535 - rightTicks;
    }
    else{}
    distanceRight = rightTicks/TICKS_PER_METER;
  }
  lastCountR = rightCount.data;
}
 
// Publish a nav_msgs::Odometry message in quaternion format
void publish_quat() {
 
  tf2::Quaternion q;
         
  q.setRPY(0, 0, odomNew.pose.pose.orientation.z);
 
  nav_msgs::Odometry quatOdom;
  quatOdom.header.stamp = odomNew.header.stamp;
  quatOdom.header.frame_id = "odom";
  quatOdom.child_frame_id = "base_link";
  quatOdom.pose.pose.position.x = odomNew.pose.pose.position.x;
  quatOdom.pose.pose.position.y = odomNew.pose.pose.position.y;
  quatOdom.pose.pose.position.z = odomNew.pose.pose.position.z;
  quatOdom.pose.pose.orientation.x = q.x();
  quatOdom.pose.pose.orientation.y = q.y();
  quatOdom.pose.pose.orientation.z = q.z();
  quatOdom.pose.pose.orientation.w = q.w();
  quatOdom.twist.twist.linear.x = odomNew.twist.twist.linear.x;
  quatOdom.twist.twist.linear.y = odomNew.twist.twist.linear.y;
  quatOdom.twist.twist.linear.z = odomNew.twist.twist.linear.z;
  quatOdom.twist.twist.angular.x = odomNew.twist.twist.angular.x;
  quatOdom.twist.twist.angular.y = odomNew.twist.twist.angular.y;
  quatOdom.twist.twist.angular.z = odomNew.twist.twist.angular.z;
 
  for(int i = 0; i<36; i++) {
    if(i == 0 || i == 7 || i == 14) {
      quatOdom.pose.covariance[i] = .01;
     }
     else if (i == 21 || i == 28 || i== 35) {
       quatOdom.pose.covariance[i] += 0.1;
     }
     else {
       quatOdom.pose.covariance[i] = 0;
     }
  }
 
  odom_data_pub_quat.publish(quatOdom);
}
 
// Update odometry information
void update_odom() {
 
  // Calculate the average distance
  double cycleDistance = (distanceRight + distanceLeft) / 2;
   
  // Calculate the number of radians the robot has turned since the last cycle
  double cycleAngle = asin((distanceRight-distanceLeft)/WHEEL_BASE);
 
  // Average angle during the last cycle
  double avgAngle = cycleAngle/2 + odomOld.pose.pose.orientation.z;
     
  if (avgAngle > PI) {
    avgAngle -= 2*PI;
  }
  else if (avgAngle < -PI) {
    avgAngle += 2*PI;
  }
  else{}
 
  // Calculate the new pose (x, y, and theta)
  odomNew.pose.pose.position.x = odomOld.pose.pose.position.x + cos(avgAngle)*cycleDistance;
  odomNew.pose.pose.position.y = odomOld.pose.pose.position.y + sin(avgAngle)*cycleDistance;
  odomNew.pose.pose.orientation.z = cycleAngle + odomOld.pose.pose.orientation.z;
 
  // Prevent lockup from a single bad cycle
  if (isnan(odomNew.pose.pose.position.x) || isnan(odomNew.pose.pose.position.y)
     || isnan(odomNew.pose.pose.position.z)) {
    odomNew.pose.pose.position.x = odomOld.pose.pose.position.x;
    odomNew.pose.pose.position.y = odomOld.pose.pose.position.y;
    odomNew.pose.pose.orientation.z = odomOld.pose.pose.orientation.z;
  }
 
  // Make sure theta stays in the correct range
  if (odomNew.pose.pose.orientation.z > PI) {
    odomNew.pose.pose.orientation.z -= 2 * PI;
  }
  else if (odomNew.pose.pose.orientation.z < -PI) {
    odomNew.pose.pose.orientation.z += 2 * PI;
  }
  else{}
 
  // Compute the velocity
  odomNew.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  odomNew.twist.twist.linear.x = cycleDistance/(odomNew.header.stamp.toSec() - odomOld.header.stamp.toSec());
  odomNew.twist.twist.angular.z = cycleAngle/(odomNew.header.stamp.toSec() - odomOld.header.stamp.toSec());
 
  // Save the pose data for the next cycle
  odomOld.pose.pose.position.x = odomNew.pose.pose.position.x;
  odomOld.pose.pose.position.y = odomNew.pose.pose.position.y;
  odomOld.pose.pose.orientation.z = odomNew.pose.pose.orientation.z;
  odomOld.header.stamp = odomNew.header.stamp;
 
  // Publish the odometry message
  odom_data_pub.publish(odomNew);
}
 
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   
  // Set the data fields of the odometry message
  odomNew.header.frame_id = "odom";
  odomNew.pose.pose.position.z = 0;
  odomNew.pose.pose.orientation.x = 0;
  odomNew.pose.pose.orientation.y = 0;
  odomNew.twist.twist.linear.x = 0;
  odomNew.twist.twist.linear.y = 0;
  odomNew.twist.twist.linear.z = 0;
  odomNew.twist.twist.angular.x = 0;
  odomNew.twist.twist.angular.y = 0;
  odomNew.twist.twist.angular.z = 0;
  odomOld.pose.pose.position.x = initialX;
  odomOld.pose.pose.position.y = initialY;
  odomOld.pose.pose.orientation.z = initialTheta;
 
  // Launch ROS and create a node
  ros::init(argc, argv, "ekf_odom_pub");
  ros::NodeHandle node;
 
  // Subscribe to ROS topics
  ros::Subscriber subForRightCounts = node.subscribe("right_ticks", 100, Calc_Right, ros::TransportHints().tcpNoDelay());
  ros::Subscriber subForLeftCounts = node.subscribe("left_ticks", 100, Calc_Left, ros::TransportHints().tcpNoDelay());
  ros::Subscriber subInitialPose = node.subscribe("slam_out_pose", 1, set_initial_2d);
 
  // Publisher of simple odom message where orientation.z is an euler angle
  odom_data_pub = node.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("odom_data_euler", 100);
 
  // Publisher of full odom message where orientation is quaternion
  odom_data_pub_quat = node.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("odom_data_quat", 100);
 
  ros::Rate loop_rate(30); 
     
  while(ros::ok()) {
     
    if(initialPoseRecieved) {
      update_odom();
      publish_quat();
    }
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
 
  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me where did i do wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are only publishing the odometry message to topics "odom_data_euler" and odom_data_quat ", but not actually broadcasting it.

You will typically use TransformStamped to achieve this. It is almost the same code-wise, but check this link out:

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/Tf2/Writing-A-Tf2-Broadcaster-Cpp.html

Comment: sorry for late reply. You're correct. i broadcasted the tf and the problem was solved!